# Need regex to remove a character in a datetime string in csv file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a csv file which has the following string:

```
"2016-10-25T14:07:49.298-07:00"
```

which I would like to replace with:

```
"2016-10-25", "14:07:49"
```

I matched the original string with a regular expression:

```
([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})[T]([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})\.[0-9]{3}-07\:00
```

but I need some help

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`, assuming `T` and `.` are unique

```
$ echo '"2016-10-25T14:07:49.298-07:00"' | awk -F'[T.]' '{print $1 "\", \"" $2 "\""}'
"2016-10-25", "14:07:49"
```

- `-F'[T.]'` assign `T` or `.` as field separator
- Then print first and second field with required formatting

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^T]+)T([^.]+).*/\1", "\2"/'
```

- `^([^T]+)` matches the portion upto `T`, and put that in captured group 1
- `T` matches `T` literally
- `([^.]+)` matches upto next `.`, and put that in captured group (2)
- `.*` matches the rest
- in the replacement, the captured groups are used with proper formatting to get desired output, `\1", "\2"`

**Example:**

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^T]+)T([^.]+).*/\1", "\2"/' <<<'"2016-10-25T14:07:49.298-07:00"'
"2016-10-25", "14:07:49"
```